# How to redirect to index page when user is not logged using Servlet?

Tags: java, session, servlets

how to redirect to a login page if the user is not logged in using servlet.

I have a login page user logs in using that and goes to home page,after navigating the user clicks on logout and just hits on back button in browser now the page goes to previously visited page, how to redirect the user to login page when using servlet?

thanks for the help and continued support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code in your jsp at the top of the page

```
if(userName.length()==0 || userType.length()==0 ){
        session.setAttribute("message", "Please Login");
         response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(path+"/"+destination));
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good approach since you are mixing presentation with logic, also this only applies to one jsp page, if you want other pages to have that functinality you'll have to copy the code to them as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use servlet ,

In web.xml

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.java.web.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/manage/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

In authentication filter ,

```
    if (visit == null) {
            servletContext.log("Redirecting to the login page.");
            session.setAttribute(Constants.ORIGINAL_VIEW_KEY, requestPath);
            String loginView = httpRequest.getContextPath() +  
            httpRequest.getServletPath() +Constants.LOGIN_PAGE;
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginView);
    } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your servlet doGet or doPost (whichever is called) you need to check if the user is logged in (I'm guessing you have the session checking mechanism) and if you see that the user is not logged in just use:

```
response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can validate user session in `Servlet` and if session is invalid or session doesn't contain userId(if at the time of session Creation you set that in session Attribute  ) then redirect it to `login` page. to disable back you need to clear the cache using following code in `jsp/servlet`.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should be doing this in Filter.

```
public void doFilter(.......){
      if(user logged in){
          filterChain.doFilter(...);
      } else {
        response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
      }
}
```

I would suggest you to use `Servlet Security Feature` which allows the container to care of `Web Application Security`.