# How to redirect to jsp login page, if user does not logged in already, Java servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, jsp, servlets

I have wrote an web application using JSP in eclipse. It has login page and other pages. After i deployed and trying to access the other pages, i am able to access without login using login page. So i want to redirect to login page whenever user trying to access other pages url before logged in through login page already. How to do that? If anyone help me on this one will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even look for : [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430216/how-to-redirect-to-index-page-when-user-is-not-logged-using-servlet)   . You have to implement a logic which checks user credentials (login username or login password) details on every page . if details present then process it further else redirect to Error page . for now i have implemented a logic which set attribute on login after login it sets all the data into session if not set error message into session . usually we will store UserClass into session since it is for your knowledge that's why i have added two attribute into session .

LoginServlet.java

```
package com.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public LoginServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
    String pword=request.getParameter("pword");
    if(null!=uname && uname!="" && pword!=null && pword!=""){
        HttpSession  session=request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("uname", uname);
        session.setAttribute("pword", pword);
        response.getWriter().append("Login SucessFully");
    }else{
          response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); //error
          HttpSession  session=request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Login Failed ");

    }
    //doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

index.jsp :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<%
String errorMessage = (String) session.getAttribute("errorMessage");
if (null !=errorMessage) { %>
<h4> <%=errorMessage %></h4>
<%}
%>
<body>
<form action="LoginServlet"  method="post" >
    Please enter your username <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" />
 <br>
    Please enter your password <input type="text" name="pword" id="pword" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

PostLogin.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Simple Page which can't be access without Login</title>
 </head>
  <%
    String uname = (String) session.getAttribute("uname");
    if (null == uname) {
    session.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Login Failed ");
    response.sendRedirect("userLogged.jsp");
    }
 %>
 <body>
 <h4>Simple Page which can be access without Login </h4>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Hope this is helpful for you Good luck . let me know if you want other details too

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in your web.xml file.

```
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

So that when run the application it will show the first page as login.jsp. Which means the authentication will go on.